# ncurses-based batch filename editor

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, batch-rename

Is there a command-line program similar to `nano` or `xtree` in looks (i.e., `ncurses`-based) that will show me all the files in a directory, that will let me work through them all making the changes needed and then applying them?

Comment: Sounds like you might be after Midnight Commander?

Comment: @wjadrea not even close.

Comment: @andrew.46 exactly like that (reminiscent of xtree from the dos pre mainstream Windows era), if you post it as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: @SPooKYiNeSS So based on the answer you've accepted, it seems like you're actually looking for a terminal-based file manager, not a rename utility. You'll probably want to edit your question to clarify.

Comment: What wanted was a nano style file/batch file renamer. This orgasm does exactly what i asked for. Because it does a hell of a lot more doesn't make my question any less accurate.

Comment: Now guess which supports auto correct decided for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application you are after is the slightly 'retro' looking application Midnight Commander, which will do what you are looking for and much more with a slightly 'nano' looking interface.

As a quick demonstration I add a screenshot here that demonstrates the movement of three files (selected with the '+' key) being moved to a sub-directory (using a menu accessed with the <kbd>F6</kbd> key):

[image]

Midnight Commander takes *a little work* until you come fully to grips with it but an excellent starting guide can be [seen here...](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_mc.php) From this same page comes the following summary of Midnight Commander's capabilities:

- Performs all the common file and directory manipulations such as *copying, moving, renaming, linking, and deleting*.
- Allows manipulation of file and directory permissions.
- Can treat remote systems (via FTP or SSH) as though they were local directories.
- Can treat archive files (like .tar and .zip) as though they were local directories.
- Allows creation of a user-defined "hotlist" of frequently used directories.
- Can search for files based on file name or file contents, and treat the search results like a directory.

Makes me think that I should be spending more time with this great application :).

**References:**

- [LinuxCommand.org: Midnight Commander](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_mc.php) A great introductory page on the usage of Midnight Commander.

Comment: I love this program and am seriously considering marriage.